# Java API to replace placeholders in a string with bean fields

Tags: java, replace

I have a requirement to create a generic method that takes an input String like `"Hello Mr. {firstName} {lastName}."` and replace the tokens with the same named fields in a provided Java bean. So, my method would look something like:

```
public String replaceStrings(String targetString, Object bean) {
    //...
}
```

Just wondering if there is an API that can provide this functionality? I can do it with Reflection API but just if there is some existing API that makes it simpler?

Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is a template engine, something like [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [StrSubstitutor](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I could achieve this by using BeanMap and StrSubstitutor as suggested : `BeanMap map = new BeanMap(obj);
                StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(map);
                resolvedString = sub.replace(targetString);`

Answer (score 0):

try apache commons EL. It implements JSTL EL language and does substitutions like this.